# SQL Ranking by when a column changes

Tags: sql, db2, ranking

I'm working on a problem in SQL where I'm trying to rank a column based on when it changes.

Basically the current table looks like this:

```
DATE        STATUS
10/18/10    A        
10/16/10    A        
10/14/10    B        
10/12/10    A
```

I want to appropriately rank the status column, based on the date column, but only when the status column changes. For example:

```
 DATE        STATUS   RANK 
 10/18/10    A        1 
 10/16/10    A        1 
 10/14/10    B        2 
 10/12/10    A        3 
 10/10/10    A        3
```

Any ideas on how to go about this? I've played around with both RANK() and DENSE_RANK() and am having trouble getting the output I want. Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: Maybe you need one more column: [Last Update] and use it instead of date. Without this column I can consider using a trigger to update the rank

Comment: Unfortunately based on the way this DB works having every date is required as it's based on when a report is sent from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 is one of the SQL DBMSes that support the `LAG` and `LEAD` OLAP windowing functions, which make it possible to compare an expression in the current row against other rows in the same partitioned window. Neither `RANK` nor `DENSE_RANK` are an exact fit for the calculation you want (a running count of status changes), but that can be accomplished with `SUM` and a binary expression:

```
WITH StatusHistory( histDate, statusCode ) AS (
    VALUES 
    ( DATE( '2010-10-10' ), 'A' ), 
    ( DATE( '2010-10-12' ), 'A' ),
    ( DATE( '2010-10-14' ), 'B' ), 
    ( DATE( '2010-10-16' ), 'A' ),
    ( DATE( '2010-10-18' ), 'A' )
)
SELECT histDate, 
statusCode, 
SMALLINT( 
    SUM( 
        CASE LAG( statusCode, 1 ) 
           OVER ( ORDER BY histDate DESC) 
        WHEN statusCode 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1
        END
    ) OVER ( ORDER BY histDate DESC )
) AS changeSeq
FROM StatusHistory
ORDER BY histDate DESC
;

HISTDATE   STATUSCODE CHANGESEQ
---------- ---------- ---------
10/18/2010 A                  1
10/16/2010 A                  1
10/14/2010 B                  2
10/12/2010 A                  3
10/10/2010 A                  3

5 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  A simple way is simply to count the number of values different from the current value, using a subquery.  Another way is to use the difference of row numbers.  Both provide a group identifier, which you then need to work a bit harder to get the ranking you want:

```
select t.date, t.status, dense_rank() over (order by mindate) as ranking
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by grp, status) as mindate   
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by date) -
                    row_number() over (partition by status order by date)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Depending on the ordering you might want an `order by mindate desc` in the outer query.